# how to add Check constraints on mysql that age calculate from Date of birth field and validate that age is greater than 18

Tags: mysql, sql

i have created table using mysql name people  which have six attribute id,name,lastname,dob(store in Date data type) ,gender, city and i want that value to be enter in dob(date of birth) to be greater than 18.how do i set this constraint please help

Comment: what have you tried and how did it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not support check constraints.  So, the only way to do this in MySQL is to create a trigger or wrap the insert in a stored procedure.

The specific logic that you would use is:

```
dob <= curdate() - interval 18 year
```

So, in almost any other database, this would look something like:

```
alter table t add constraint chk_t_dob check (dob <= curdate() - interval '18' year);
```

(Note:  date operations vary among databases.)

Comment: ...or just use a query

Comment: As of MySQL 8.0.16, `check` is now supported: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following, on this the 24th June 2017...

```
CREATE TABLE dobs(dob DATE NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO dobs (dob)
SELECT '2012-01-01' x FROM (SELECT 1) a WHERE FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(),'2012-01-01') / 365.24) >= 18;

INSERT INTO dobs (dob)
SELECT '1975-01-01' x FROM (SELECT 1) a WHERE FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(),'1975-01-01') / 365.24) >= 18;

INSERT INTO dobs (dob)
SELECT '1999-06-25' x FROM (SELECT 1) a WHERE FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(),'1999-06-25') / 365.24) >= 18;

INSERT INTO dobs (dob)
SELECT '1999-06-24' x FROM (SELECT 1) a WHERE FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(),'1999-06-24') / 365.24) >= 18;

SELECT * FROM dobs;
+------------+
| dob        |
+------------+
| 1975-01-01 |
| 1999-06-24 |
+------------+
```

Answer (score -1):

[for full explanation consider the link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp)

```
//use the CHECK constraint to limit the range for age

create table DOB(

age int not null check(age>=18),

);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).